# How to synthesize a Helmholtz resonator (à la Ocarina for iPhone)

Tags: algorithm, audio, instruments

How do I synthesize a [Helmholtz resonator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_resonance), for example an [ocarina](http://songbirdocarina.com/blog/?p=202)?

Has anyone come across open source code to do this?

Or even the underlying mathematical technique, from which I could probably figure out how to code it up?

Comment: I love this site, but sometimes it leaves me scratching my head. This is a precise question.  If I ask for an algorithm to generate prime numbers,  nobody will vote to close,  because everyone understands that question.  But this is a specialist question,  and it can be answered directly.  It will only mean something if you understand the field.   These people should not be voting to close it just because they don't understand it.

Comment: Why was this closed? Looks perfectly appropriate to me: clear, specific, non-argumentative and programming-related. And I'm interested in the answers...

Comment: http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/  Smule has created a port of this called Chip

Comment: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidE7FD493967705EE4C3499B47E674213BFF98D8BD.aspx?s=socket Thankyou Biappi

Comment: This seems on topic enough for me. I'd venture to say that @RobertHarvey agrees with me, since he's provided an answer to this question. I've re-opened this, but do keep in mind that the community is free to reverse that decision.

Answer (score 2):

Your general approach should be to simulate the process of resonating a cavity by blowing air over a hole in the cavity.

Have a look at this article for a good starting point:

**Synthesizing a Flute** 
http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/oct03/articles/synthsecrets.htm

See also http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14587584